# I am getting error on Post method of MVC controller using AngularJS

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am using angualarJS and asp.net web API but my code always breaks on post request in the asp.net controller and this is the error I got

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code Additional
>   information: Value cannot be null.

this is the MVC method

```
 // POST: api/ProductCategory
    public HttpResponseMessage Post(ProductCategory pcate)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            this.pcat.pcategory.Add(pcate);
            this.pcat.SaveChanges();
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, pcate);
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, pcate);
        }
    }
```

this is the angularJS controller

```
  var appcat = angular.module("PharmacyControllers", ['ngRoute']);

appcat.controller("createController", ['$scope', '$http', '$location', function ($scope, $http, $location)
{
    $scope.submit = function()
    {
        //converting the object to JSON
        var obj = {

            Name: $scope.Name
        };
        //alert(obj);
        $http.post("/api/productCategory/", this.obj).success(function (data) {
            $location.path('/list');
        }).error(function (data) {

            $scope.error = "An error has occured while adding product Category! " + data.ExceptionMessage;
        });
    }

}]);
```

thanks in advanced

Comment: Can you show a JSON request and a input model for controller?

Comment: this is the JSON
 var obj = $.param({
            pcate: {
                Name: $scope.Name
            }
        });

Comment: Have you checked in debug mode if `pcate` is not `null`? Also have you tried to check what is actually posted?

Comment: @LLJanneh I mean API model ProductCategory and actual JSON (looks like {...}).

Comment: the API public class ProductCategory
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Key]
        public int CID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public String Name { get; set; }
        
    }
the JSON format is 
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a local variable `obj` here:

```
var obj = {
    Name: $scope.Name
};
```

But then you are trying to post `this.obj` to your API:

```
$http.post("/api/productCategory/", this.obj)
```

Either create the `this.obj` instead of the `var obj` or pass `obj` instead of `this.obj` on your post.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing from:

```
$http.post("/api/productCategory/", this.obj).success(function (data) {
```

to:

```
$http.post("/api/productCategory/", { pcate: obj }).success(function (data) {
```

Comment: this is not working! I also try  var obj = $.param({
            pcate: {
                Name: $scope.Name
            }
        });
but still the  same error

Comment: @LLJanneh What does the ProductCategory class look like?